# Почему не работает условие, которое извещает о том что комментарий ожидает проверки WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток. 
На сайте нужно было реализовать вывод комментариев и стандартная форма вывода чуть не подходила, по-этому нашел вот такой шаблон, который мне подошел:

```
<ol class="commentlist">
        <?php
        function verstaka_comment($comment, $args, $depth){
        $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; ?>
        <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
            <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
                <div class="comment-author vcard">

                    <?php printf(__('<div class="fn">%s</div>'), get_comment_author_link()) ?>
                    <div class="comment-meta commentmetadata">
                        <span><?php printf(__('%1$s'), get_comment_date()) ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
                    <p style="font-style:bold"><?php _e('Ваш комментарий ожидает проверки.') ?></p>
                    <br>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="div"><?php comment_text() ?></div>
                <div class="reply">
                    <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }
            $args = array(
                'reply_text' => 'Ответить',
                'callback' => 'verstaka_comment'
            );
            wp_list_comments($args);
            ?>
            <div class="comment-pagg"><?php paginate_comments_links( array('prev_text' => '«', 'next_text' => '»') ); ?></div>
    </ol>
```

в нем есть условие которое отвечает за вывод надписи после того как кто-то оставил коммент:

```
<?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
   <p style="font-style:bold"><?php _e('Ваш комментарий ожидает проверки.') ?></p>
```

Но почему то оно не срабатывает , хотя комментарий оставляется (т.е приходит в админку и я его могу опубликовать потом), но нету этого оповещения которое мне нужно 100% ) 
Плагин ставить не хочу , так как для этого все есть в WP , вот только эту проблему исправить и все будет гуд.
Посоветуйте что можно сделать или где ошибка ??

Comment: Проверьте, что в $comment->comment_approved. var_dump сделайте, к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Код правильный, изначально взят [отсюда](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_comments) и слегка модифицирован. На моем сайте точно такой же код проверки approved, и он работает.

Скорее всего, дело в том, что комментарии администратора сайта не попадают на модерацию. Попробуйте оставить комментарий от незарегистрированного пользователя или не администратора.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы условие `if ($comment->comment_approved == '0')` срабатывало, надо чтобы на вход вашей функции `function verstaka_comment($comment, $args, $depth)` в переменную $comment в принципе поступали неодобренные комментарии.
А они не поступают, потому и проверять нечего.

А не поступают они оттого, что при отправке комментария обязательно должно быть заполнено поле e-mail - именно по нему ВП будет определять принадлежность комментария автору.

Так что ставим в админке галку "Автор комментария должен указать имя и e-mail", обязываем пользователей вводить e-mail и все будет.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте изменить код

```
<?php  $args = array(
                'reply_text' => 'Ответить',
                'callback' => 'verstaka_comment'
        );
        wp_list_comments($args);
?>
```

на

```
<?php global $post; ?>

<?php $wp_comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query(); ?>
               
<?php $comments = (array)$wp_comment_query->query( array('post_id' => $post->ID, 'status' => 'all')); ?>
               
<?php  $args = array(
                'reply_text' => 'Ответить',
                'callback' => 'verstaka_comment'
        );
        wp_list_comments($args, $comments);
?>
```